# Javascript for loops with dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, forms, form-api

I am writing a Google form using a script so that I can pull the data from a Google spreadsheet and generate a page for each event based on a list of events which are of unknown length.

I have worked out that I can create the pages I need using this loop, with my list of events, `eventvalues`:

```
for (var i = 2; i < eventvalues.length; i += 1)
{
    var page = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(eventvalues[i][0]);
}
```

I would like to end up with variables `Page1`, `Page2`, `Page3`, etc... all the way to `eventvalues.length`

Currently the variable `page` is used by the last page only and all others are not assigned to a variable because of being re-assigned.

Comment: I'm doing some spring cleaning and noticed you hadn't accepted my answer (which appears to be correct). If you're okay with it, do you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 5):

You could use an array to store the pages.

```
var pages = [];

for (var i = 2; i < eventvalues.length; i+=1){
  pages.push(form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(eventvalues[i][0]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the eval function.

```
    for (var i = 2; i < eventvalues.length; i+=1){
        eval("var page" + i + " = " + form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(eventvalues[i][0]+";");
   } 
console.log(page1,page2,page3,page4,page5);
```

Comment: Eval is one of the quickest way to introduce errors and security issues into your JavaScript.